# OSPF LSA Group Pacing

Tags: cisco, routing, network-protocols, ospf

Is **LSA group pacing** enabled by default in Cisco IOS or something that needs to be configured under the OSPF process? How do you determine if it is currently enabled or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is LSA group pacing enabled by default in Cisco IOS or something that
>   needs to be configured under the OSPF process?

Yes, It is enabled by default in Cisco IOS, the default value is 240s. You can change it by command in mode config-router

```
timers lsa-group-pacing <value>
```

Where value is range from 1 to 1800 seconds

> How do you determine if it is currently enabled or not?

In enable mode, run:

```
show ip ospf timers lsa-group
```